# cakephp3をターミナルからインストールできない

Tags: php, cakephp

今現在、XAMPPを使ってターミナル上でcakephp3をインストールしようと思っています。

いろいろ調べてみて、
composerをインストールして、cakephpをインストールするという手順で行いました。

XAMPPのhtdocs内にcakephpというフォルダを作り、
現在は、「composer.phar」というプロジェクトと「bookmarker」というフォルダがあります。

ただ、ターミナル上で

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist -s dev cakephp/app bookmarker
```

と打ったら、

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.1 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3].
```

とエラーが表示されます。
調べてみて、php.intlが有効化されていないということで、
xamppfileのphp.intlを有効化したのですが、まだこのエラーが続いています。

ブラウザでは、

```
    Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp_youtube/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line 23

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp_youtube/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line 23
```

このように表示されていて、イマイチよく分かっていません。

XAMPPをやり直しても、ターミナルでbookmarkerというフォルダを作り直しても同じエラーが起きるのですが、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ターミナル上で `php -m | grep intl` を実行して何も表示されなければ、intl モジュールをインストールする必要があります。

Comment: sudo pecl install intlでintlモジュールをインストールして、php.iniのextension=php_intl.dllを有効化したのですが、php -m | grep intlでまだ何も表示されないのですが、他にすべきこととかありますでしょうか？

Comment: php.ini ですが、`extension=intl.so` の方を有効化してみて下さい(`php_intl.dll`はWindows版のライブラリです)。

Comment: 無事intlはインストールできたのですが、
You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line 38
というエラーが表示されてしまい、アプリがまだ起動しないのですが、原因などわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: xampp上のphpとosx上のphpと混同していませんか？

Comment: xamppfileのphp.iniではないということですかね！？

Comment: xampp側に設定するで正解です。ターミナル側だとosx側のphpが実行されている場合もあるかなと思いましたので。`<?php phpinfo();` と書いたファイルを置いて、intlが有効化されているか確認してみたらどうでしょう。

Comment: なるほどです。vim etc/php.iniで新たにextension=intl.soという記述をしていました。ただ、xamppfileのphp.iniにはextension=intl.soという文字列が無かったのですが、追記する形になりますでしょうか？
また、<?php phpinfo();>というファイルを新たにcakephpフォルダに作るということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、php.iniへの追記でよいです。追記した後はサーバーの再起動を忘れずに。phpinfoについては`phpinfo.php`とでも名前を付けてwebrootにでも置いてみてください。

Comment: phpinfo.phpというファイルをwebroot内に作り、XAMPPを再起動したのですが、同じエラーが出てしまいます。
cakephpフォルダ内でvim /etc/php.iniが残ってしまっているのが原因ですかね！？
あと、xamppのphp.iniファイルの
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
は無効化にしたままの方が良いのでしょうか？